# Solve Master Equation (Differential Equation) Numerically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

any ideas on how to solve the following master equation numerically?
$$ \frac {\partial P(x,y,t)} {\partial t} = rP(x-1,y,t) + (1-2r)P(x,y-1,t) + rP(x+1,y-2,t)+\gamma P(x,y+1,t) - (1 + \gamma)P(x,y,t) $$

with boundary condition $ P(x,y,0) = \delta_{x,1} \delta_{y,0}$

Here, the $\delta_{x,y} $ is a kronecker delta symbol, which is 1 if $x=y$ and 0 otherwise.

This is a master equation for a stochastic branching process. What should I do with those $ P(x-1,y,t) , P(x+1,y-2,t), etc $ in the RSH ?

Comment: I suppose $x$ and $y$ are integers because at other places there is no way for the solution to become nonzero?

Comment: View each $P(x,y,t)$ as a time-dependent variable & make a vector out of all of these (I assume there are finitely many?). Then, your system is 1st order, linear & high-dimensional.

Comment: yes, now I could solve this numerically. Is there any way to solve it analytically ? I hear something called lattice Green function might come handy. Any ideas ?

Comment: You could use a mean field approximation and solve the mean values. Another way is using Taylor expansion and derive a linearised Fokker Plank Equation. Somehow you need to assume something. I think Lattice Green function you assume a probability density distribution.